# hybernate-c3p0 Update no persistence provider

Tags: java, jpa

I updated my hibernate-c3p0 from 5.4.10Final to 6.1.0Final and now Iam geeting "no persistence provider for unit....". Before that it worked all fine and I only changed the version in pom.xml and notthing  else.
Can someone help me solve this problem?
 my pom.xml looks like this (I removed the first part cause I think the important things are the dependencies):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Websocket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- validation annotations like @NotNULL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOGGING libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Commons -->
       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.clerezza.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.json.simple</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mapping objects from json to java-instance -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- persistence -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-M3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-grizzly2-http-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework/jersey-test-framework-core-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!---https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QR-Code generator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- PDF generator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- push notifications -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.72.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: provide your pom

Comment: And you also updated all other Hibernate depencencies to 6.1.0. Final?

Comment: You have `c3p0` and `hibernate-c3p0` which could cause issues. Also you have `hibernate-entitymanager` which supposedly was moved to `hibernate-core` which again could cause issues. And lastly, if you update 1 hibernate part to a newer version, update all. `hibernate-envers` is still on version 5.4.10.Final